# Advice needed to understand a logic problem

Tags: logic

I have difficulty understanding this problem and would appreciate if someone can explain why my solution is wrong:

You meet a person who either always lies or always tells the truth. He flips a standard coin and makes a the following statement: The toss is head if and only if I am telling the truth.

So what is the result of the toss?

My solution: Define p: the toss is head and q:I am telling the truth.

Suppose he always lies, then p iff q is false and q is false, so p must be true. 
But since q is false, i.e. he is not telling the truth, we can conclude that the toss is not head, so p is false??

Comment: Suppose the coin says Liar on the tails side and Truth-teller on the heads side. He says “The toss describes me.” I think this is an identical problem, but easier to see the answer to.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that your (possible) liar never said 'the toss is heads', so knowing he's a liar doesn't mean we can conclude the toss was really tails. What he did say was that 'the toss is heads iff I'm truthful:'  ($p\iff q)$. Because we're assuming him a liar, we can take the negation of *that* statement: $\neg(p\iff q)$.

Drawing up the truth-tables, we find that $\neg(p\iff q)$ is true when exactly one of $p$ and $q$ are:

- $p,q$ both true; $p\iff q$ true; $\neg(p\iff q)$ false
- $p$ true $q$ false; $p\iff q$ false; $\neg(p\iff q)$ true
- $p$ false $q$ true; $p\iff q$ false; $\neg(p\iff q)$ true
- $p$ false $q$ false; $p\iff q$ true; $\neg(p\iff q)$ false.

Using this, we can then conclude that...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. If we assume that he is a liar, then it means he is not telling the truth, can we conclude that the toss is not head via the contrapositive of p implies q ?

Comment: I don't see where you get $p$ implies $q$ from, though.

Comment: p iff q, so p implies q and q implies p

Comment: Right, but because we've assumed he's lying we're also assuming $p \iff q$ is false.